# Grep and SED not working in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to replace a url in more than 1000 files (using PowerShell). 
That is replace `thomas.corp.test.com:81/gt/se.ashx` with `george.corp.test.com:91/gt/se.ashx`.

I am able to execute it in a linux machine using the following command.

```
grep -lr http:\/\/thomas\.corp\.test\.com:81\/gt\/se\.ashx . |
  xargs sed -i '' 's/http:\/\/thomas\.corp\.test\.com:81\/gt\/se\.ashx/https:\/\/george\.corp\.test\.com:91\/gt\/se\.ashx/g'
```

Need help in finding out an equivalent for PowerShell.

Comment: Whoever is keeping negative.. please be specific

Comment: Did not downvote, but how can you hope to find linux commands on a Windows OS? If you want to have a bash environment on Windows, you could google for gnuwin32 (simple port of GNU tools), MinGW (near to a bash console) or Cygwin (almost a Linux emulation on Windows). Your current question is poor because it shows no research. You should read [ask] to see haw questions are supposed to be asked here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: *"...how can you hope to find linux commands on a Windows OS?"* The [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), aka "Ubuntu on Windows", is an optional feature for 64-bit Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

try Something like this :

```
$odl="thomas.corp.test.com:81/gt/se.ashx"
$new="george.corp.test.com:91/gt/se.ashx"

select-string -Path "c:\temp\*.*" -Pattern $odl -SimpleMatch | %{$curpath=$_.path; (get-content $curpath -Raw) -replace $odl, $new | Out-File $curpath}
```

Comment: get-childitem c:\somedir -recurse -include *.* | 
 select -expand fullname |
  foreach {
            (Get-Content $_) -replace $old,$new |
             Set-Content $_
  }

Comment: Can u please tell the difference?

Comment: With your méthods 2 problems: getchilditem take directory too not only file. AND your replace is apply on all file not only file wich content your old strind -> low performance

Comment: sls doesn't recurse but handles only files containing the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

$old="thomas.corp.test.com:81/gt/se.ashx"

$new="george.corp.test.com:91/gt/se.ashx"

get-childitem c:\somedir -recurse -include *.* | 
select -expand fullname |
  foreach 
{
            (Get-Content $*) -replace $old,$new |
             Set-Content $*

}